# What environment variable do I need to configure to move my .bash* files to a .bash directory?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I read this page from the [bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files), which tells me that bash reads `/etc/profile` then my home directory. I wasn't able to find an environment variable to tell bash to read some subdirectory, ie `~/.bash.d`. I suspect that I need to put some line in `/etc/profile` along the lines of:

`BASHENVIRONMENTVARIABLE="~/.bash.d"`

ie. for `zsh` that variable is `ZDOTDIR`.

Answer (score 1):

`/etc/profile` has the following description:

```
if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

How about writing a script to read files under `~/.bash.d` as same as this?

```
if [ -d ~/.bash.d ]; then
  for i in ~/.bash.d/*; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

Or maybe you can do it with `eval` command.

```
eval $(cat ~/.bash.d/*)
```

Answer (score 0):

The startup scripts (`~/.bashrc`, `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, etc) are all expected to be located in the home folder.

To source the startup from a different folder, simply add a `source` (or `.`) command to the "official", and place all the setting in the desired location (`~/.bash.d`)

```
# This is ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bash.d/.bashrc
```

```
# This is ~/.bash_login
source ~/.bash.d/.bash_login
```

Note that the 'BASH_ENV' will usually include absolute path, to allow it to work regardless of the directory where bash in invoked.

Comment: Doesn't solve the fundamental problem that I don't want to see these `.bash*` files in my home directory.